# Wordpress: italics, bold, and links off baseline

Tags: wordpress, text, offset

On Wordpress after adding italic, bold, or hyperlink elements to text, the text becomes offset from the baseline of normal text. I'm using the Elegantica theme. Is there a solution for this?

My site: http://www.lfvaa-sample.com/

Examples of this problem can be found on the home page at the bottom with the hyperlinked text "Learn More" and on the LinkedFlow page under resources with the italicized text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the case of your "learn more" links at the bottom, the culprit appears to be

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

in your style.css

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can see when I turn that rule off in firebug, the text aligns properly. Tested with the italic on the other page and the same rule is affecting that text too.

[image]